# How to copy a subset of subfolders recursively

Tags: copy

I have a large number of folders, each of which containing multiple subfolders. Something like this

```
/mnt/data1/Folder1/subjfolder1, /mnt/data/Folder1/subjfolder2, /mnt/data/Folder1/subjfolder3
/mnt/data1/Folder2/subjfolder1, /mnt/data/Folder2/subjfolder2, /mnt/data/Folder2/subjfolder3
...
```

I like to copy Folder1, Folder2, etc. but only the subjfolder2 in each folder to a new location, say data2. Something like this:

```
/mnt/data2/Folder1/subjfolder2
/mnt/data2/Folder2/subjfolder2
...
```

I don't want to copy the entire content of Folder1,2 etc, just the subjfolder2 in each folder. I hope this is clear. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of thing can be done with simple shell globs:

```
cp -rt path/to/destination/ /mnt/data2/Folder?/subjfolder2
```

(matches names in which `Folder` is followed by any single character)

```
cp -rt path/to/destination/ /mnt/data2/Folder[0-9]/subjfolder2
```

(matches names in which `Folder` is followed by any single *decimal digit*)

```
cp -rt path/to/destination/ /mnt/data2/Folder*/subjfolder2
```

(matches names in which `Folder` is followed by any string).

Alternatively, to match a specific set of folders you could use *brace expansion*

```
cp -rt path/to/destination/ /mnt/data2/Folder{1..17}/subjfolder2
```